# Does Realm for .NET support blobs, byte[] type storage?

Tags: .net, xamarin, realm

Can we store byte[] in [PCL version](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/tree/master/Realm.PCL) of Realm.io? And how efficient is it at lets say 100GB worth of 3MB images?

Comment: Note that there's not any such thing as a usable _PCL Version_. Realm has a native core so you always have both the Realm.PCL assembly to provide the declarations to your PCL and one or more native Realm C# DLLs used by your platform-specific app builds. (Currently we only ship IOS and Android builds via NuGet).

Comment: Understand, any sqllite based solution would need a native library, using Avacache now but it is lacking in performance.

Comment: Just to be clear: Realm is not based on SQLite, but it's own core database engine.

Comment: Didn't realize it runs it's own engine, that's great.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: Realm Xamarin supports `byte[]` since v0.75.0.

<strike>We don't support binary data yet. It is coming very soon though (only not as byte arrays but via the [System.Data.Linq.Binary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary(v=vs.110).aspx) class). See [Issue #510](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/510)</strike>

Realm is as a rule of thumb not optimized for large arrays of binary data and 100GB seems unrealistically high for something to be running on a phone or tablet.

Comment: Common use case of course not, but hopefully we're moving past that. When you consider IoT devices like RaspberryPi and fixed purpose tablets and phones 100GB is not at all unrealistic and in fact what our customers require. In general modern SQL DBs shouldn't have issues with binary data, perhaps SQLite isn't optimized for that, but it sure be nice to have a reliable store that works cross platform vs using the file system.

Comment: Also since the payloads are larger and these devices don't have much memory, would be good to support Streams as well.

Comment: There is no problem storing big binary blobs - it's usually just not needed unless you wan to transfer the file as one big thingy. Storing pictures in files and references to those files in a string property is usually better since you don't search in the picture data anyway.

Comment: I think that the ability to store images in an encrypted realm is a big advantage, otherwise you have to encrypt and decrypt them separately

Comment: Thats actually a very good point - didn't consider that feature.

Comment: Yes that was my default approach (linking to files), but dealing with file systems cross platform is not fun. If a usable approach exists with DB backed stores I would prefer to use that initially.